# Erro no width Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

Estou querendo posicionar uma div no site, porém no Chrome aparece de um jeito e no Firefox de outro, ou seja, a div no Chrome posiciona corretamente, mas no Firefox fica mais para a esquerda do que no Chrome e saí do layout. Estou usando o seguinte código:

```
 <div style="width: 500px; display: table; border: 0px #000 solid;"> 
  <div style="width: 460px; position: absolute; border: 0px #000 solid; float: left; margin-left: -130px"> 
    Conteúdo
    </div>
</div>
```

Porque isso acontece? Teria alguma solução para essa diferença?

Obrigado!

Comment: Aqui a `div` esta saindo da página no Chrome. É isso mesmo que deseja?

Comment: Na verdade no Chrome aparece perfeitamente, o que preciso é que no Firefox apareça como no Chrome, mas não é isso que acontece...

Comment: Insira um [CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) no seu CSS e verifique se o problema persiste.

Comment: Coloquei no site, acima de todo o CSS que existe e o problema persiste.

Comment: Bom amigo, acho que o melhor é você nos contar o que está tentando fazer, pois ainda não entendi. Depois que explicar poderemos lhe dizer a melhor forma ou se sua solução está indo pelo caminho certo =)
De qualquer forma dei uma refatorada no seu código somente aplicando corretamente alguns coicietos: http://jsfiddle.net/qLh6zre1/
1º: para usar absolute numa dive filha, obrigatoriamente a div pai deve ter seu valor de position definido como 'relative', se não fizer isso (que foi seu caso) a div com 'absolute' vai estar posicionada em relação ao body. 2º: usando absolute não precisa usar float

Comment: Existe um script em JavaScript que determina em que browser o site é aberto, implementando isso você pode corrigir o seu problema facilmente.